# GLEW - Visual Studio Intellisense not showing complete function Signatures

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense, glew

Recently, I have been learning OpenGL using GLEW. For this, I am using visual studio community IDE. For some reason, the visual studio intellisense doesn't show the complete function signature, when I hover over any function defined  in glew, it only shows the macro defined in the glew.h, instead of the complete function definition.

For example, if i hover over glVertexAttribPointer(), it shows:
   #define glVertexAttribPointer GLEW_GET_FUN(_glewVertexAttribPointer)
                                                                        .
                                                                                                                                             How do I get the intellisense to show the complete function signature? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It won't show normally by hovering over the function name because it's just a macro define, and not a function itself. For example glVertexAttribPointer is defined as:

```
#define glVertexAttribPointer GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewVertexAttribPointer)
```

__glewVertexAttribPointer is a typedef hidden behind another macro define of PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC, which is defined as:

```
typedef void(__stdcall *PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC)(GLuint index, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized, GLsizei stride, const void *pointer)
```

With that many levels of indirection it's not surprising that the IDE struggles to treat this as just an ordinary function and give you the signature. But, at least in my Visual Studio 2017 Community it's simply enough to type glVertexAttribPointer and then as soon you open the bracket the function signature will appear. It will also show when typing a comma when separating arguments. This is what it looks like in my Visual Studio as soon as I open the bracket:

[image]

It comes up with a really handy list of all the arguments, and makes bold the argument that you are currently typing. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that I know.. It's just that i was watching a video on youtube and the person was using the visual studio version and when that person hovered over the function it displayed the complete function decription.. I thought that there might be some settings that i can change to get the intellisense to give complete decription.. Anyways thanks for the help...

Comment: @Nikhil Bansal I'd love to know if there's a way. Have you got a link to the video you watched?

Comment: Unfortunately No!! But the above suggestion helped, I actually found out that pressing Ctrl + shift + space with the cursor inside the function parameter list gives the same list as above, so it makes it easy to understand the existing code.